# Will Combining Js, Css and Images into one single file improve performance?

Tags: javascript, css, performance

My question might confuse that I want to combine all javascript into one file and all css into one and all images into one file. But that's not the case. I already have minified gzipped  one js file, one css file and one image file. All these files are being loaded from CDN. As a possible performance improvement, I am asked to concat all these resources and create one js file which includes everything. 
While I believe that, loading 3 files separately may happen in parallel and will result in better performance, I am given a reason that, 
" with slow internet, connection to same destination multiple time takes more time compared to single connection and single file will be loaded much faster compared to 3 files being loaded from same destination(CDN). "

Could you please share your suggestions on whether it will improve performance or not? 
Has anyone done this before?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What's the mechanism you plan to use to embed images in a javscript file?

Comment: if you have a CDN from 3rd party, do you need to care about the performance hits which affects their service when you are requesting the files? Sure, if you use a spritesheet instead of separate images, user has less data to be downloaded so the page will load faster. In practise, however, rarely I see image galleries etc. done using those. I would use other techniques like paging.. avoid making heavy content pages.. etc  :]

Comment: @recursive I don't have exact mechanism, But I have heard that Images can be included into css and then css can be included in js. Need to do some more research on this.

Comment: @Mauno I am not caring about performance of CDN service. My overall goal is to reduce load time for my files. Yes, we have image sprites.

Comment: To be honest with you.. I would recommend KISS, I have been developing many web services and the solution you are after just feels too over-engineering to me. Continue using CDN, minify/concat js so that you won't have that many requests, use css sprites to combine similar images (e.g. icons) and avoid big images in general. That should be enough.

Comment: @user2850929:  Using the technique you are proposing would require using base64 encoding of your images to be used as data: urls.  Base64 in utf-8 encoded javascript is bigger than the size of the original image.  In fact, I doubt you could ever even break even with this strategy.

Comment: @recursive, after gzipping css file, base64 size effect will be minimized. 
We are trying to solve a problem when users internet speed is very slow(in mobile).  I believe, doing this and comparing with existing solution would be the best way to decide.

Comment: There's really no solid way to answer this question.  Depending on request latency, bandwidth, and browser performance, it's anyone's guess.  My gut reaction is that it's probably not worth doing, but only you know the scenario you have in mind.